# Qual seria a maneira mais eficiente de replicar esse código? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, objetos, construtor

### Dúvida

Com esse código, eu consigo só criar e manipular um "funcionario", eu queria conseguir adicionar mais funcionários clicando em um botão e manipular os dados deles.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      Funcionario: <div id="func"></div>
      <button id="alternome">Alterar nome</button>
      Salario: R$<div id="salario"></div>
      <button id="aumenta">+</button><button id="abaixa">-</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
function funcionario(){
//altera div func
var f = document.getElementById("func");
var s2 = f.innerHTML;
f.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o nome do funcionario??");
//pos-alteramento de nome
var a= document.getElementById("alternome");
a.onclick = function alternome(){
    f.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o nome atual?");
}
//altera div salario
var n=document.getElementById("salario");
var s1 = n.innerHTML;
n.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o salario?");

//aumenta valor
var m=document.getElementById("aumenta");
m.onclick = function aumenta(){
    //gambiarra para aumentar o valor 100X
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    n.innerHTML++;
    }
};
//decrementa valor
var o=document.getElementById("abaixa");
o.onclick = function abaixa(){
    //gambiarra para abaixar o valor 100X 
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(n.innerHTML==0){
            continue;
        }
    n.innerHTML--;
    }
};
}
//tem q colocar essa função pra funcionar os bagui
setTimeout(funcionario, 500);
```

Comment: Olá sr. fizemos sugestões de código. Verifique se elas lhe ajudam. Caso a reposta seja positiva, e marque como resolvido, ou se vc tiver gostado da resposta dê um UP para ajudar na nossa reputação.

Answer (score -1):

Tenho um código que pode lhe ajudar.
Isso ajuda em muitos casos.

Coloque o 'script' depois do 'body'.

```js
  // AQUI EU SETO O MÉTODO TEMPLATE
  String.prototype.template = function (obj) {
      return this.replace(/\{\{([\w]+)\}\}/g, function (str, prop) {
          return obj[prop];
      });
  };

  // ESTE É O MODELO QUE VOCÊ IRÁ USAR
  var modelo = '' +
       'Funcionario: <div id="func">{{nome}}</div>' +
       '<button id="alternome">Alterar nome</button>' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="idfunc" id="idfunc" value="{{id}}" />' +
       'Salario: <div id="salario">R${{salario}}</div>' +
       '<button id="aumenta">+</button><button id="abaixa">-</button>';

  // ESSE É O JSON, QUE PODER SER RECEBIDO DE UMA REQUISIÇÃO. FICA A DICA
     var users = [
         {
             id      : 1,
             nome    : "JOAO",
             salario : 2000
         },{
             id      : 2,
             nome    : "MARIA",
             salario : 3000
         }
     ];

     // AQUI EU ESCREVO NA DIV
       users.forEach(function(o, i){        
        document.getElementById("funcionarios").innerHTML += modelo.template(users[i]);     
       });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="funcionarios"></div>
 </body>
 

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Transforma esses IDs em classes uma vez que IDs têm de ser unicos na página. Dessa maneira podes criar uma lógica relativa ao elemento pai de cada funcionário e em vêz de

```
var f = document.getElementById("func");
```

podes usar uma busca por classes a partir do elemento que queres editar:

```
var f = el.querySelector('.nome');
```

Desenvolvi mais o teu código para o que pediste e ficou assim:

```js
function editarFuncionario(el) {
    //altera div func
    var f = el.querySelector('.nome');
    var s2 = f.innerHTML;
    f.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o nome do funcionario??");
    //pos-alteramento de nome
    var a = el.querySelector(".alternome");
    a.onclick = function alternome() {
        f.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o nome atual?");
    };
    //altera div salario
    var n = el.querySelector(".salario");
    var s1 = n.innerHTML;
    n.innerHTML = prompt("Qual o salario?");

    //aumenta valor
    var m = el.querySelector(".aumenta");
    m.onclick = function aumenta() {
        n.innerHTML = (Number(n.innerHTML) || 0) + 100;
    };
    //decrementa valor
    var o = el.querySelector(".abaixa");
    o.onclick = function abaixa() {
        n.innerHTML = (Number(n.innerHTML) || 0) - 100;
    };
}

function removerFuncionario(el) {
    el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
}

function adicionarFuncionario(el) {
    var novo = el.cloneNode(true);
    el.parentElement.appendChild(novo);
    auscultador(novo);
}

function closest(el, selector) {
    while (el && !el.matches(selector)) {
        el = el.parentElement;
    }
    return el;
}

function auscultador(el) {
    var buttons = el.querySelectorAll('.ui-buttons');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var el = closest(e.target, '.funcionario');
            var action = e.target.dataset.action;
            if (action == 'editar') return editarFuncionario(el);
            if (action == 'remover') return removerFuncionario(el);
            if (action == 'adicionar') return adicionarFuncionario(el);
        });
    }
}

auscultador(document.body);
```

```css
.funcionario {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="funcionario">
    <div> Funcionario:
        <div class="nome"></div>
        <button class="alternome">Alterar nome</button>
    </div>
    <div> Salario: R$
        <div class="salario"></div>
        <button class="aumenta">+</button>
        <button class="abaixa">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-buttons">
        <button data-action="adicionar">Adicionar novo functionario</button>
        <button data-action="editar">Editar functionario</button>
        <button data-action="remover">Remover functionario</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Exemplo online: https://jsfiddle.net/tnehgpd5/